# How can I get PhD in Hinduism

Tags: history, vedanta

I just want to ask that is there any university in India or outside India which is able to award Ph.D. in Hinduism. As whatever I searched on Google, there is no university in the India. Please suggest if there is any.

Comment: There is no PHD in hinduism, the most important limbs of hinduism are available for formal studies these are Sanskrit language , Vedas.

Comment: @Yogi I think you can do a PhD in Indology or Hinduism studies.

Comment: Mentioned answers are good resources to find doctorate programs. 
I am having two specific subquestions:
1. if I want to pursue PhD on specific area, say on Lord Shiva, Is it possible? 
2 I need remote Phd programs from India to anywhere.
If any idea, please give hint,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Hindu University of America offers a Doctoral Degree in Hinduism: http://www.hua.edu/doctorate_programs.php

Answer (score 1):

the topic of religion comes under term "Philosophy" and there are many Indian universities offering doctoral studies on any subject including Hinduism. You need google using the key word "Phd + Philosophy". alternatively you can also search using term "Indologist'

You can browse the weblink apaonline.org/?page=gradguide which has data on philosophy education programs primarily in USA and other locations.